# Codeigniter htaccess and routing for a SEO controller name in urls

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2

I'm having a controller named : main_controller
all the links in my app refers to it with url like : `/main_controller/...`

Now i want to insert some **SEO** in all this and change the url to a more seo one like `/seo_name_for_controller/...`

Instead of doing a full manual search & replace for all occurences which may be source of errors, I wish i could do this using **htaccess** with something like :

```
RewriteRule ^/main_controller/(.*)$ /seo_name_for_controller/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then using **routes.php** to finish the process like :

```
$route['seo_name_for_controller/(:any)'] = "main_controller/$1";
```

Is it possible or will it cause an infinite loop ? does someone have a code example for this ?

Comment: The `$route` declaration alone should be enough for it to work - no need to add things to the `.htaccess`file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't cause a problem. The CI Route is not technically redirecting, it is just using the URI pattern to call a specific controller. This should work.

Have you tried it to see what happens though? Your question suggests no trial.

Answer (score 0):

thanx for your reply, i followed your advice and I tried to confirm with :

**htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^main_controller/(.*)$ seo_controller/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Routes.php**

```
$route['seo_controller/(:any)'] = "main_controller/$1";
```

**inpage urls are :**

```
http://local.com/main_controller
```

When clicked it works and after redirecting+routing it ends in :

```
http://local.com/seo_controller
```

But i'm sad it's not "totally invisible".

because it first use the "normal url" (/main_controller/) in the adress bar before it get redirected.
It works in the end and execute /main_controller/ actions while the last url is /seo_controller/.

But it is not really satisfying, i would have had a totally invisible redirection. So i think i'm on the way for manual search and replace ;) then use only routing.